# How to convert MapPoint to latitude/longitude in ArcGIS for Xamarine Android

Tags: arcgis-10.0, android

How to convert MapPoint to latitude/longitude in ArcGIS for Xamarine Android?
Below is my code.

MapPoint pointGeometry = new MapPoint(e.Location.X, Location.Y,SpatialReferences.Wgs84);

Answer (score 2):

This plagued me for a bit...here's the answer.

The MapPoint can be expressed in either Wgs84 (latitude / longitude) or WebMercator which is some other system of coordinates.

Since you specified SpatialReferences.Wgs84 your pointGeometry will be a MapPoint where the X value is the longitude and the Y is the latitude.

How does one get a Wgs84 (latitude / longitude ) point from a MapPoint that is WebMercator?

This did the job for me:

```
MapPoint mpLatLon = Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.GeometryEngine.Project(mapPointObjectToConvert, SpatialReferences.Wgs84) as MapPoint;
```

Then mpLatLon.X is your longitude and mpLatLon.Y is your latitude.